# Change from Flask to NodeJS or UDP or use more threads in Flask to improve communication?

Tags: android, node.js, http, flask, udp

I'm creating a simple android application to control mouse of a desktop in the local network.

I've figured out how to create the expected behavior, some times it works perfectly, but some times it is slow.

The app uses Volley with JsonObjectRequest to communicate with server.
Server is using Flask and HTTP POSTs.

**I was thinking in 5 things to improve:**

1. Change server to NodeJS
2. Use UDP protocol, since I do not need acknowledge.
3. Use more than one thread in Flask
4. Change Volley to OkHttp or other http library. (**Probably** Volley is not the problem, but I can be wrong.)
5. Change from POST to GET (sounds stupid)

So if the problem is in the **server**:

1. Should I use more threads in Flask?
2. Or use UDP with Flask is enough to respond to +/- 60 req/sec?
3. Or its necessary to change my server to NodeJS?
4. Or to get 60 r/s I will need both, NodeJS and UDP?

Any other alternative is valid too! Thanks.

**Flask Code**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import win32api, win32con
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/mouse", methods=['POST'])
def mouse():        
    x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    win32api.SetCursorPos( (x + request.json['x'], y + request.json['y'] ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

In **Android**, after detecting touch and movement in view, get deltaX and deltaY and POST to /mouse as x and y. I also limited the max numbers of request per second but dindn't work good.

```
MouseController.MOUSE_FRAME = 30;
private View.OnTouchListener onMouseTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if(motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            mouseX = motionEvent.getX();
            mouseY = motionEvent.getY();
        }


        if(motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            if( now - lastTime > (1000/MouseController.MOUSE_FRAME)){
                float newX = motionEvent.getX();
                float newY = motionEvent.getY();
                float deltaX = newX - mouseX;
                float deltaY = newY - mouseY;
                mouseX = newX;
                mouseY = newY;

                mouseController.move(deltaX, deltaY);
                lastTime = now;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: You will need to post Python code for us to help. Switching stack is probably not needed. If you are sending UDP packets then HTTP can't be used so Flask isn't going to help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I changed to UDP communication.

Based on this two tutorials:

Android UDP: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example

Python UDP: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

The problem was solved, and the movement is smooth now. And yes, was that simple.